# Jquery Sortable Connect List + PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I've been searching everywhere for a solution without luck.

What I'm searching for i a way to merge the example found here http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists with PHP/MySQL.

There are several examples out there that works with just the one list i.e. http://www.wil-linssen.com/musings/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

But I haven't found a single example with multiple lists.

Does anyone have ha solution or a link to an example that works?

Thanks! 
/David

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback (example taken & extended from the docs):

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    update : function(event, ui) {
        //ui.sender is the list the item comes from
        //ui.item is the current item that moved
        //ui.position is the current position
    }

}).disableSelection();
```

Now do any ajaxy thing you want in the callback using the `ui` paremeter.